# How do you include npm libraries in a node.js app

Tags: node.js, ncurses

I'm trying to create a little app with node-ncurses which I installed over `npm install ncurses`

with this library install i'm trying to run the examples for node-ncurses from the following

https://github.com/mscdex/node-ncurses/tree/master/examples

But I get path errors with the examples for `require('ncurses')`, what is wrong?

My ncurses library is install into `~/.npm/` which seems correct to me.

Answer (score 3):

You want to be installing them locally into the same folder of your project. If you miss out the `-g` flag and just run `npm install ncurses` within your project directory, you should then be able to run `require("ncurses")` just fine. All NPM modules installed locally goes into a `node_modules` folder within your project.

A little further hint, if you install with:

```
npm install ncurses --save
```

That will add `ncurses` to your `package.json` as a dependency, which means any other dev who might check out your project can run `npm install` in the project's directory and automatically get `ncurses` installed as it's listed in `package.json` as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Without the `-g` flag anything you install with NPM with install into a node_modules folder relative to where you ran the command.

My first recommendation would be to make sure that you are in the working directory of your project and then install `ncurses` again.

Here is an old, but relevant [blog post](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) about how it was designed.